# Shortcut key for client side comment in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that using the keys `ctrl+K` `ctrl+C` comments the selection but that is a server side comment i.e. it inserts `<%--` *commented text* `--%>`. Rather than server side comment I need to know the shortcut for the client side HTML comment which is

```html
<!-- commented text -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page is ASP.NET specific page ex- *.aspx,*.ascx then the comment will be <%--commented text--%> and if it is html page then comment will be `<!--commented text-->` and the shortcut for both is "CTRL+K+C".